# Why did Luke's mom stop tucking him in?

Tags: plot-explanation, better-watch-out

At some point in *Better Watch Out* Luke's mom suddenly stops tucking him in before he goes to sleep and Luke wonders why. Ashley says that she knows the reason why but she doesn't tell Luke, even when he asked her.

So why did Luke's mom stop tucking him in?

Comment: At the moment it's a little unclear if you're asking why Luke's mom stopped tucking him in or why Ashley said that she knew the reason why. Can you elaborate a little? Do we know why Luke's mom stopped and just not how Ashley knows that? Or is the primary question why Luke's mom stopped and the Ashley part only supplementary?

Comment: I think the movie wants to imply us that it is a mystery why his mom stopped from tucking him in since he has maybe difficulty in sleeping when as well as Luke himself is also wondering why his mom one day has suddenly stopped from doing such thing. Then Ashley answer that she know the reason why his mom stopped from doing that and Luke asked her to tell him why but Ash just closed her eyes and didn't respond.

Comment: Okay, I clarified the question a little based on your explanations.

Comment: perhaps his mom saw that evil inside of him and she's unable to tuck him in anymore.. and ashley realizes this too?